# Federation query on Dbpedia and Wikidata

Tags: eclipse, sparql, jena, dbpedia, wikidata

I'm doing federation query exercise. I want the list of films that stars with leonardio di caprio and also the list of directors that worked with him.

I have to design federated SPARQL  query over Wikidata and Dbpedia. I have to run the query  through FEDx.

Here's the query. This is done in Eclipse. Also tested on the wikidata endpoint.

```
   PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
            PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
            PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>  
            PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>  
            PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
            PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
            PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#>

SELECT ?film  ?director   WHERE 
{
     ?film  wdt:P161 wd:Q38111.
    ?film  wdt:P57 ?director.
   ?film rdf:type dbo:Film .  
   ?film dbo:starring dbr:Leonardo_DiCaprio .
} LIMIT 10
```

When I ran the code, I get an error "Rate limit exceeds".

Can anyone explain what is the error and also I think there might be some problem with the query. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Ask the FedX developers.

Comment: I'm still not sure whether you understood that the result will be probably empty given that DBpedia and wikidata are using different idientifiers aks URIs for their resources, thus, a `?film` in DBpedia will be `http://dbpedia.org/resource/...` and in Wikidata `https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/...` That means, the join on `?film` will for sure be empty

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for letting me know. I'm new to federation query. I'm finding it a bit tough  to understand.

Comment: Looks like homework ... and like [Construct RDF graph on federated query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50584568).